# Global key binding throughout the whole application to open chm file on ctrl+h

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to open a chm file in a java program. Now I want this chm file to be opened when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> anywhere in the whole program.

I am using the follwing code to open the chm file and it's working. The issue is to open the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> throughout the project.

```
public class Testproject {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hh.exe path of the chm file here/abc.chm");
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exceptioin is"+ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use KeyBindings, not KeyListener, btw this code not talking about something

Comment: hmm ... is this really a Swing application? Wondering because I'm not seeing any swing code in the snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ways to add key bindings does so on a per-compnent basis, so you'd have to create bindings for all your top-level windows, probably including dialogs, which would be pretty annoying. So you have to grab events at some central place in the evend dispatch system.

One possible way appears to be [`Toolkit.addAWTEventListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener%28java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long%29), with a custom listener as the first argument and [`KEY_EVENT_MASK`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AWTEvent.html#KEY_EVENT_MASK) as the second. The listener registered in this way *should* get notified of all keystroks, so you can cast them to [`KeyEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) and inspect them whether they are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and act accordingly.

Comment: could be done, but is using a missile when a hammer would do ;-) For grabbing keyEvents across a swing app with many windows (having many windos is not really recommended, but alas ..) a KeyEventDispatcher is the appropriate tool.

Comment: @kleopatra: then please write an answer giving details on that. In particular, you might want to describe *why* you consider it more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in my comment, the class designed for application global interception of KeyEvents is a [KeyEventDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/KeyEventDispatcher.html):

> A KeyEventDispatcher cooperates with the current KeyboardFocusManager in the targeting and dispatching of all KeyEvents. KeyEventDispatchers registered with the current KeyboardFocusManager will receive KeyEvents before they are dispatched to their targets, allowing each KeyEventDispatcher to retarget the event, consume it, dispatch the event itself, or make other changes.

So the task is to implement a dispatcher which does what you want in its dispatch(KeyEvent) method, something like:

```
public class MyDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher {

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!e.isConsumed()) {
            if (processMyStuff(e)) {
                e.consume();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean processMyStuff(KeyEvent e) {
        if (!isMyTrigger(e)) return false;
        doMyStuff();
        return true; 
    }

}

// usage:
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager()
    .addKeyEventDispatcher(new MyDispatcher());
```

Note that you *could* achieve the goal by adding a global listener to the Toolkit with some caveats:

- as a general rule, use the most fitting tool for a job, especially if it's designed for serving the exact requirement
- an AWTEventListener might not work in security-restricted contexts